# fullpage.js only on certain pages

Tags: wordpress, fullpage.js

is it possible to have fullpage.js only on home page, and on another to have normal web page. So far, when I put framework to work, it work perfectly on home page, but now I want to have another page which is normal, without any scrolling options (I putted code without fullpage and section classes), and it does not work. Can not scroll down at all. Any solutions? I am using wordpress as a cms.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to enqueue the plugin conditionally. Register js in your functions.php and the enqueue it only in front-page.php, or what your theme is using for the front. Alternatively you can enqueue it in functions.php in `if(is_front_page())` statement.